# Fasted method to create and fill new column in DynamoDB with Python & boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to update multiple DynamoDB tables with a new column that will contain values. The DDB tables contain over 10 million items. I'm unable to use the `BatchWriteItem` boto3 method as that overwrites the entire item and I need to preserve the existing items.

I've attempted to use the `UpdateItem` boto3 method but it is very slow for updating this many items.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to batch together multiple `UpdateItem` calls instead of having to send millions of calls?
2. What other methods can I utilize to speed up the process of updating all these items with the new column?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: BatchWriteItem cannot update items, period, so I think you're going to have to do individual UpdateItem requests. Also see [Managing settings on DynamoDB provisioned capacity tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html) and [Considerations when changing read/write Capacity Mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/switching.capacitymode.html).

Comment: @jarmod I see, thank you. Is it possible to parallelize `UpdateItem` requests in Python to increase speed? For example, with 8 threads we'd be able to send 8 `UpdateItem` requests at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways you can speed things up:

1. Using `BatchExecuteStatement` will allow you to do a batch update of up to 25 items in a single request.
2. Use Parallel Scan to retrieve the keys and multiple threads to parallelize your work
3. Use AWS Glue to provide distributed compute, this is similar to #2 but you have a lot more processing power by using Spark distribution.

Comment: Thank you Lee! My idea (using your suggestions) is to run `BatchExecuteStatement` on 4-5 threads to hopefully greatly increase performance. Can `boto3` handle being run in separate threads like this?

Comment: Yes, the low level client is thread safe.